# How do I prove the convexity of this function under constraint?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Here is a function $f:\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}_{+}:
  \sum_{i=1}^n{x_i} =1\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as,

$
f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \log(x_i) & \text{ if } \; x > 0 \\
0 & \text{ if } x \leq 0
\end{array}
\right.
$

I know that by seeing $-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \log(x_i)$ itself it is a simple question that could be easily tearing it into n small functions and each of them could be proved to be convex by calculating the second derivatives. However, with the constraint that $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}_{+}: \sum_{i=1}^n{x_i} =1\}$, I am not so sure that I can still prove its convexity/concavity through this way. Any idea? Also, when $x \leq 0$, does that affect the convexity/concavity of the function?

Comment: Your domain is $R^{n}_{+}$, so there won't be any values of $x_{i}$ that are actually less than $0$.  The limit as $x$ goes to 0 of $-x \log(x)$ is $0$, so the function is continuous there.  You've got a more serious issue with the minus sign in the definition of $f(x)$.  Your function isn't convex.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I think its concave instead am I right?

Comment: yes it's concave (you can check the simple version of your problem in 2 dimensions with the function $y=-x\log x - (1-x)\log (1-x)$

Comment: Do I have to apply the constraint that $\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i} =1\$ into account of the proof?

Comment: If a function is concave over its domain, then it's concave over any convex subset of its domain.